# Ruby - Can variable set equal to object of custom class transfer custom class to the variable?

Tags: ruby, arrays, class, object, inheritance

```
class New_Class
   def initialize
      @array = ['1A','2A','1B','2C']
   end
   def remove_letters
      @array.map do |rmv|
         rmv.sub /([0-9])([A-Z])/, '\1'
      end
   end
   def show_array
      @array.each do |element|
         puts element
      end
   end
end

array = New_Class.new
new_array = array.remove_letters
puts new_array.class #=> Array
new_array.each do |element|
   puts element   #=>1,2,1,2
end
array.show_array   #=>1A,2A,1B,2C
new_array.show_array   #=>Undefined method error since it's an object of type Array not New_Class
```

How would I make new_array an object of type New_Class instead of Array?
This doesn't work:

```
new_array = New_Class.new
new_array = array.remove_letters
```

Still says new_array is of type Array.

I played around with clone and dup but couldn't get it to work that way either. Thanks!

Comment: Side note, it's a convention in Ruby to use 2-space indent, not 4-space.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? What is all of this for?

Comment: I have an array of a custom class that changes length throughout my program.  At any point I need to derive an array from that array but without the letters.  I then need to compare the derived array to others of that custom class while using methods from said class.  What I'm really doing is slightly more complicated but it's the same logic as in my example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `remove_letters` method returns an array, which you then assign to `new_array`. If you want `new_array` to be another instance of `New_Class` instead, then you need to return another instance of `NewClass` from your `remove_letters` method, not an array:

```
def initialize(values = ['1A','2A','1B','2C']) 
  @array = values
end

def remove_letters
  New_Class.new(@array.map { |rmv| rmv.sub(/([0-9])([A-Z])/, '\1') })      
end
```

Above, I modify `initialize` to use your array as a default, if an initial array value isn't passed to `New_Class.new`, then it uses `['1A','2A','1B','2C']` as a default.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks I had been struggling with that for a while.

Comment: @quelleck if you feel like I have answered your question to your satisfaction, please consider accepting my answer, and upvoting it later when you earn enough reputation to do so (it's 15 rep).